# Определение точки зависания C#-программы

Tags: c#, отладка

Есть программа, которая достаточно редко зависает. Выполнение программы происходит на удалённых машинах, и возможности запустить отладчик не имеется. Запуск внешнего профайлера более реален, но тоже сопряжён с огромными сложностями. Как можно, не прибегая к профайлеру, определить точку зависания программы?

Вариант "подробное логирование работы программы в файловую систему" плохо подходит. Программа состоит из около 20 тысяч строк кода, а виснет редко.

Пробовал Process Explorer, но он очень странно работает (либо я не разобрался). Если успеть "поймать" поток, вошедший в бесконечный цикл, то его стек посмотреть вполне возможно. Но этот поток достаточно быстро исчезает (то ли в РЕ, то ли его действительно убивает среда).

Вариант создания ещё одного приложения, приложения-монитора, вполне приемлем. Если можно как-то создать дамп процесса или получить информацию о потоках этого процесса, то было бы здорово. Если есть какой-то готовый инструмент, то ещё лучше.

Answer (score 11):

Я пользовался такой идеей:

1. Выясняем, произошло ли зависание. Для этого время создаётся фоновый поток, который время от времени пытается выполнить пустой колбэк в главном потоке, и если выполнение занимает *подозрительно много*, запускается реакция:

   ```
   async Task LoopChecks(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       try
       {
           // исключить реакцию, если мы побывали в Sleep/Hibernate
           SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
           while (true)
           {
               // ожидание следующей проверки
               await Task.Delay(checkTimeout, ct);
               PowerStateChanged = false;
               var pingSuccess = await Check(ct);
               if (!pingSuccess && !PowerStateChanged)
               {
                   OnHang(); // колбэк, вызывается когда приложение зависло
                   await Unhung(ct);
                   OnUnhang(); // колбэк, вызывается когда приложение отвисло
               }
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged -= OnPowerModeChanged;
       }
   }

   async Task<bool> Check(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       var ping = PingMain(ct);
       var delay = Task.Delay(pingTimeout, ct);
       var succeeded = (await Task.WhenAny(ping, delay)) == ping;
       ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       return succeeded;
   }

   Task PingMain(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                           () => { /* nothing */ },
                           ct,
                           TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness,
                           mainTaskScheduler);
   }

   void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       PowerStateChanged = true;
   }
   ```

   Свойство `PowerStateChanged` должно быть, разумеется, защищено внутри `lock`'ом, поскольку будет изменяться из непонятно какого потока внутри `OnPowerModeChanged`.
2. В случае, если зависание сдетектировано, происходило много вещей. Пользователю показывался (в новом UI-потоке, разумеется) диалог о зависании программы (который автоматически скрывался при отвисании). Запускалось внешнее приложение, которое снимало скриншот и запускало [отладчик командной строки `mdbg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) со скриптом, который присоединялся к процессу, снимал список загруженных модулей, список потоков и их стеков, и отсоединялся:

   ```
   !a {0} !l -v modules !w -v all !block !fo p !de !quit
   ```

   Результаты потом можно было упаковать и отправить «домой» основной программой.

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить пример использования данной фичи напрямую в программе? (А то несколько моментов не ясно)

Comment: @AresGod: Ну, в конструкторе проверяю, из UI-потока запущена функция или нет и запоминаю scheduler при помощи `mainTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();`. Затем запускаю таск `LoopChecks` на отдельном потоке. Экземпляр класса создаю в конструкторе приложения, подписываюсь у него на `MainThreadHangs` и там запускаю нужную логику с показом диалогов и сохранению дампа.

Comment: @AresGod: Лучше спросите конкретно по непонятным пунктам.

Comment: если не сложно, маленькую ConsoleApp или WPF(с одной кнопкой) с реализацией. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @AresGod: Ох. Это ж код писать надо :) Ну вот вам: https://pastebin.com/BtadgXFp

Comment: большущее спасибо) Именно то что нужно

Comment: @AresGod: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.

Answer (score 8):

Вы *можете* создать дамп процесса и затем исследовать его с помощью [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg).

***Создать дамп*** можно:

- с помощью Process Explorer (в контекстном меню процесса выберите `Create Dump -> Create Full Dump`)
- с помощью собственно WinDbg. Для этого откройте WinDbg, выберите команду меню  `File -> Attach to а Process`, и выберите ваш процесс из списка. В открывшемся окне внизу будет строка для ввода команд. Выполните `.dump /ma D:\Dump_file_name.dmp`, затем `.detach`
- с помощью стандартного диспетчера задач Windows. В контекстном меню процесса есть команда создания дампа, которая сохраняет дамп в директорию Temp и сообщает путь к файлу дампа

Последний способ конечно оптимальный, потому что можно довольно просто проинструктировать юзеров как создать дамп, но честно говоря не уверен, что он создает дамп с достаточным количеством информации. Поэтому пробуйте, но если третий способ не подойдет, используйте первые два.

Чтобы ***исследовать дамп*** вам потребуется:

- **Windbg**
- Библиотека **sos.dll**, которая учит **WinDbg** работать с управляемым кодом. Эту библиотеку не надо устанавливать отдельно, она уже есть на вашей машине с Visual Studio, причем в нескольких вариантах. Пример пути к 32-битной версии для .Net 4 - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll`
- **sosex.dll** - библиотека расширений для **sos.dll**, которая добавляет дополнительные команды. Вот [здесь](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx), например, версия для .Net 4.

Когда будете работать со всем этим следите за разрядностью. Если у вас 32-битное приложение, вам надо использовать 32-битные версии WinDbg, sos.dll и sosex.dll. Кроме того при выборе версий sos.dll и sosex.dll надо следить за версией .NET фреймворка.

Ваша сессия работы с дампом памяти будет начинаться так. В WinDbg откройте дамп командой меню `File -> Open Crash Dump`. Затем выполните следующие команды:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll // подгружаем sos.dll
.symfix C:\Путь_к_исходникам_проекта // подгружаем символы
.load C:\Tools\sosex_32\sosex.dll // подгружаем sosex
!bhi /* sosex попросит вас выполнить эту команду, команда создаст 
        индекс объектов кучи для ускорения работы команд */
```

С этого момента ваша рабочая среда готова и вы можете исследовать дамп с помощью команд из **sos.dll** (официальная справка [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx)) и из **sosex.dll** (краткую справку по камандам найдете в файле *readme*, в загруженном архиве с *sosex*).

Конкретные рекомендации по поиску проблемы дать сложно. Я таким способом искал дедлоки в игре. В моем случае работа начиналась с вызова команды **!dlk**, которая очень часто сразу показывает где находится дедлок. Если эта команда не давала результатов, я сам искал проблемные блокировки с помощью команд **!mlocks** (показывает все залоченные объекты) и **!mwaits** (показывает все потоки, находящиеся в режиме ожидания).

Если в вашем приложении есть какая-то многопоточность, возможно, вам тоже стоит начать с этого. Либо просто начните с просмотра потоков (**!threads**) и стека (**!clrstack**) и по мере продвижения решайте какие еще команды вам могут понадобиться. Будет интересно!

Answer (score 6):

Если зависания долговременные - просто запустите с отладкой из студии, сделайте действия приводящие к зависанию, и в момент зависания нажмите в студии на кнопку "Break All"(с иконкой "пауза") - попадете в места в коде, которые выполняются в данный момент.

Если же зависания кратковременны, и поймать нужный момент не удается, то для этого в студии в меню отладки есть профайлер - с его помощью вы можете легко определить места в коде которые дольше всего выполняются, которые чаще всего выполняются, больше всего тратят ресурсы процессора, видеокарты, съедают оперативную память, нагружают сеть, требуют наибольших затрат электроэнергии и т.д.

Comment: К сожалению, я забыл указать, что выполнение программы происходит на удалённых машинах. Возможности запустить отладчик нет. Запуск внешнего профайлера более реален, но тоже сопряжён с огромными сложностями.