# WPF баг в приложении или в фреймворке?

Tags: c#, wpf, framework, отладка, windbg

Есть приложение на WPF на .net 4.5

Приложение установлено на трех десятках компьютеров идентичной конфигурации с установленным из образа софтом и системой.

В совершенно любом месте приложения иногда (может раз в день, а может раз в несколько дней и не на каждом компе) что-то происходит и оно уходит в себя визуально замерев на последнем кадре. 
При этом процессор загружен на 25%, т.е. фактически полностью одно из четырех ядер, но ОС не считает приложение зависшим и никак на него не реагирует. 
Тестовый стенд аналогичной конфигурации так же установленный из образа ни разу не удалось привести к такой же зависшей ситуации хотя оставляли на несколько дней автокликалку по разным разделам и поведениям.

Подключиться дебагером и посмотреть что происходит на боевом терминале нет возможности - система в промышленной эксплуатации и доступ затруднен.
Все что удалось - это снять дамп памяти и попытаться его проанализировать.
Под windbg есть пара тредов, которые находятся глубоко в недрах presentationcore и никаких методов самого приложения, которые могли бы крутиться в цикле нет.

Я встречал пару ссылок для приложений на .net 4.0, которые описывали похожее поведение, но методы решения не помогли.

К сожалению даже не знаю что привести из кода, чтобы более точно описать ситуацию потому как софт достаточно большой. Биндингов не используем. Активно пользуемся Invoke-ами для подгрузки данных в контролы. Используем анимацию.

Есть ли у кого-то мысли как еще можно проверить кто виноват?
Может есть специалисты в windbg ,например, или другом дебагере, чтобы помочь определить причину зависания. Я честно говоря в таких дебагерах не спец а открытый дамп в студии ничего толком не показывает - только какие-то системные библиотеки и методы.
Могу загрузить дамп в windbg и выполнить какие-либо команды и предоставить результаты. Только вопрос в том какие команды выполнять?

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Дополнения.

1. Видео играет но только на главной странице - там обычно зависаний вроде не было. Под фразой "Замерев на последнем кадре", я подразумевал что остается статичная картинка интерфейса в момент скролла, например, списка продуктов. Хотя замирает не только на скролле, а даже если товаров нет вообще.
2. sos я подгружал. Он показывает что фреймворк 4.0 хотя приложение скомпилировано под 4.5 - тут есть какая-то разница?
3. Основной поток выдает такой стек. В ScrollBox.xaml.cs вообще нет никаких инвоков только вызовы анимаций, а в 47-й строке ( если @47 действительно означает номер строки) просто описана проперть класса

   ```
   0:000> !CLRStack -a
   OS Thread Id: 0x168c (0)
   Child SP       IP Call Site
   0044ef54 738c3547 [InlinedCallFrame: 0044ef54] 
   0044ef50 70ebd30c DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
       PARAMETERS:
           <no data>

   0044ef54 70e9a01d [InlinedCallFrame: 0044ef54] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   0044ef88 70e9a01d System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
       PARAMETERS:
           this (0x0044ef8c) = 0x026a7cf0
           frame (<CLR reg>) = 0x026a8fb0
       LOCALS:
           <no data>
           0x0044ef88 = 0x00000000
           <no data>

   0044efd4 70e99d09 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
       PARAMETERS:
           frame = <no data>
       LOCALS:
           <no data>

   0044efe0 70e93df3 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()

   0044eff0 6a78d3df System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
       PARAMETERS:
           this = <no data>
           ignore = <no data>

   0044effc 6a78d037 System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
       PARAMETERS:
           this (<CLR reg>) = 0x026a3094
           window = <no data>
       LOCALS:
           <no data>
           <no data>

   0044f020 6a78cdd2 System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
       PARAMETERS:
           this = <no data>
           window = <no data>

   0044f030 6a78cc07 System.Windows.Application.Run()
       PARAMETERS:
           this = <no data>

   0044f03c 002000a4 know2buy.App.Main() [c:\Users\kc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\kdm_ds\know2buy_DS\know2buy_Furniture\Controls\ScrollBox.xaml.cs @ 47]
       LOCALS:
           0x0044f040 = 0x026a3094

   0044f1d4 738b3e22 [GCFrame: 0044f1d4]
   ```

Comment: Ну, ваш вопрос из серии «у меня приложение на C++ вылетает, это баг в программе или в компиляторе?» Кто ж знает?

Comment: В любом случае, попробуйте воспроизвести. Заведите логирование, посмотрите, что делает программа в момент подвисания. Попробуйте спровоцировать баг. «_замерев на последнем кадре_» — вы показываете видео?

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот совет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431101/10105

Comment: Если вы сняли дамп, выкладывайте stack trace UI-потока.

Comment: `.prefer_dml 1`, `~*e!CLRStack`, ищите трейс с `System.Windows.Application.Run`. потом переключайтесь на этот поток с `~_номер_s`, и смотрите трейс с параметрами, `!CLRStack -a`.

Comment: @VladD подправил вопрос и выложил стектрейс. Не вижу, к сожалению, где тут проблема. Софт повторюсь не виснет наглухо. Замирает вся активность, но процессор при этом нагружает полностью одно ядро (если привязать софт к одному ядру) либо размазывает по всем ядрам, но неизменно 25% от четырех ядер. Дедлоков вроде не обнаружено  через dlk от sosex.

Comment: @VladimirRiadchenko: Поэтому трейсу ничего особенного не видно, да. Попробуйте и правда «пинговать» UI-поток, может, проблема в нём. Кстати! Может быть, проблема в оборудовании? Например, DirectX, которую использует WPF, не договорилась с драйверами видеокарты. (Если конфигурация везде одинаковая, это может быть причиной.)

Comment: @VladimirRiadchenko помимо `dlk` поcмотрите какой вывод дают `mwaits` и `mlocks`.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev mlocks выдает кучу записей вида ClrThread  DbgThread  OsThread    LockType    Lock      LockLevel
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x1        0          0x168c      thinlock    026a217c  (recursion:0)

Comment: mwaits вида ClrThread  DbgThread  OsThread    LockType    Lock      LockLevel
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x2        2          0x5a4       <Unknown>   00000000                
Понять бы еще что с этим дальше делать. И все таки мне кажется локи привели бы просто к зависшему приложению, а тут идет где-то бесконечный цикл с постоянной загрузкой процессора.

Comment: @VladimirRiadchenko mwaits выводит потоки находящиеся в режиме ожидания, в записи которую вы привели в качестве примера номер Clr-потока - 0x2. Если вы посмотрите стек потока с этим номером, вы увидите в какой точке поток остановился.

Comment: @VladimirRiadchenko я не дебажил таким образом wpf-приложений, и не могу точно сказать как лучше искать причину проблемы. Я таким образом искал дедлоки в windows-службе. Dlk не всегда давал результат, и тогда я вызывал mwaits и внимательно изучал каждый поток который там был, в итоге проблема находилась.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам есть смысл продолжить искать причину зависания с помощью *windbg*.

Обратите внимание вот на что:

1. Чтобы *windbg* давал информативный вывод, надо подключать к нему *sos.dll* - это библиотека, которая учит *windbg* работать с управляемым кодом. Если вы этого не делали - сделайте и скорее всего увидите гораздо больше информации
2. Дополнительно можно воспользоваться библиотекой *sosex.dll*, которая представляет собой расширение для *sos.dll* (добавляет дополнительные команды)
3. Не забудьте подгрузить символы вашего приложения, вы можете не видеть вашего стека из-за того, что не подгружены символы
4. В целом внимательно читайте вывод windbg и перепроверяйте все что делаете - по моему опыту очень часто бывает, что причина того, что не удалось получить нужную информацию из дампа не в том что ее там нет, а в том что что-то сделано неправильно при запросе информации

Чтобы определиться какие команды юзать - изучите список доступных команд в *sos.dll* ([здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx)) и в *sosex.dll* (он есть в readme файле, который поставляется вместе с библиотекой).

Подробнее о том где взять эти библиотеки и как с ними работать можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432378/179987).

Пробуйте просматривать потоки или поискать дедлоки (команда *dlk* из *sosex.dll*)